# CF application scope mutable in Mura?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, mura

First off, thanks for taking the time to read and potentially answer this question. Also, I'm a relative noob to CF.

I have a .cfm file which gets called when a user fills out a web form (i.e. the form action points to it with a method of POST). That .cfm then POSTs another form to a data-tracking endpoint, and proceeds to the next user-facing view.

The problem I'm running into, and I've run into so far throughout this Mura project, is that the Application scope doesn't work the way I'd expect it to. For example, I set application vars like so:

```
<cfif isDefined(form.campaign) AND len(form.campaign) >
        <cfset application.campaign = form.campaign />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset application.campaign = 'default' />
</cfif>
<cfif isDefined(form.channel) AND len(form.channel)>
        <cfset application.channel = form.channel />
    <cfelse>
        <cfset application.channel = form.channel/>
</cfif>
```

Which if cfdump'd in this context comes out to the expected values based on what I'm passing it. However, once I forward on to the next view (using `cflocation`), and `cfdump` the application scope, those two keys aren't available.

I was under the impression that application scope was supposed to persist for the the session, more or less?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but I assume the actual code uses `isDefined("form.campaign")` (with quotes) rather than `isDefined(form.campaign)`? Otherwise, the code would error when that variable was not defined.

Comment: The `application` scope is mutable, but I'm thinking based on your question that you really should be using the `session` scope. The `application` scope is per application - meaning all users on your application will reference the same application scope. The `session` scope is per user. Both scopes will persist until their defined timeout value in `application.cfc`

Comment: It's hard to see the issue because you have not included the actual code. The code sample you gave has a couple of issues. As Leigh already pointed out, you need to quote the values for the `isDefined()` function. This code is also incorrectly assigning the `form.channel` variable when it does not exist - which would throw an error. In theory there should not be an issue assigning values to the application and/or session scope and those values should persist. So most likely something is wrong with your code but we cannot see what that is with the example given.

Comment: Ok I think I discovered the issue. At some point we put an empty application.cfc in our template root, which then overrode the apllication.cfc at the wwwroot. So whenever I'd try to call a method or property of application, it would return null or "method does not exist". This would probably also explain why session scope isn't working for us.

Comment: @Leigh there's a lot of things about our code that probably isn't best practice... trying to fix that. Thanks for the heads up on that syntax error.

Comment: @Roll_Fizzlebeef - Okay.  There were some good points in the other comments as well a) The second cfelse statement assigns a variable that does not exist. b) It seems likely this code should really be using the session scope, [rather than application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010891/cf-application-scope-mutable-in-mura?noredirect=1#comment75227120_44010891)

Comment: Also, if you think the solution will be helpful to someone else, feel free to post it as an official "answer". (That is allowed on S.O.) Otherwise, just delete the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Make sure there is only one instance of Application.cfX anywhere in your application.

A team member had created a file called application.cfm in a higher level of the directory than Application.cfc, which took precedence over the proper file and broke a ton of stuff.

It was added to try to make HTTP requests to .cfm files used for business logic/form processing. This permitted that, but created many other problems.

Removed that file from the directory, moved form processing logic to /remote (which Mura supports for HTTP requests) and refactored some code; application and session scopes are once again available throughout the application, as is Mura($) scope.